# Django console giving not found error for api even though its visible in browser

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django backend setup. In that I have a few folders, base (app that holds my models), a folder named "api" that has a `views.py` and `urls.py` for my apis, and a folder called backend (djangos base folder where `settings.py`, `wsgi.py`, etc are).

Now, I already have a few APIs in my views.py (in api folder) that are linked and working, and I just tried to create a new one. Although I did the same steps, followed he same linkage, this API is not working when accessed from my frontend, the console says:

```
Not Found: /api/getmodel/
\[25/Mar/2024 22:36:50\] "GET /api/getmodel/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3116"
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getmodel/` I'm seeing the default djangorestframework view so I know that the view exists and there is infact something on that link. Here are the relevant files:

`urls.py` (in api folder):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import  views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenRefreshView,
)
from .views import MyTokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
    path('registeruser/', views.register_user),
    path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('createmodel/', views.create_model),
    path('getmodel/', views.fetch_model),
]
```

`views.py` (in api folder):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from base.models import User, HumanModel
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from django.http import JsonResponse
import subprocess
import os


#login tokenizer (working fine)

#login api here (working fine)

#example of working API
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_model(request):
    data = request.data
    username = request.user.username
    print(username)
    print(data)
    
    #do a whole bunch of processing (left out for simplicity)

#api that is NOT working (saying not found)
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def fetch_model(request):
    try:
        # Attempt to fetch the HumanModel instance associated with the current user
        human_model = HumanModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        # Check if a model_path exists
        if human_model.model_path:
            # Return the model_path if it exists
            return Response({'model_path': human_model.model_path})
        else:
            # Return a message indicating the model_path is not available
            return Response({'message': 'No model path exists for the current user.'})
    except HumanModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Return a response indicating no HumanModel instance exists for the current user
        return Response({'message': 'No model information found for the current user.'}, status=404)
```

I already have the urls.py in the base backend folder working correctly, and it works with my other apis, so I'm lost as to what the issue is. Here is the file for reference:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include('api.urls'))
]
```

I dont think its a configuration issue in linking my api folder to `urls.py` in backend folder, as the other api (login, register, createmodel) all work. And again, I can go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getmodel/` and see the djangorestframework default view, but when my frontend code tries using axios to go to that url, it says "not found" in the DJANGO console. Any ideas?

Look above for explanation, even though the view is visible in the browser its saying not found in the console. I have the correct proxy set up in my react frontend in `package.json`, my other apis work. Heres how im fetching from my frontend:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchModelPath = async () => {
      if (!authTokens) return; // If there are no auth tokens, return early
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/getmodel/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authTokens.access}`, 
          },
        });
        if (response.data.model_path) {
          setModelPath(response.data.model_path);
        } else {
          setModelPath("create");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was an error fetching the model path", error);
        setModelPath("create");
      }
    };

    fetchModelPath();
  }, [authTokens]);
```

Comment: did you add api to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend may be first trying [HEADs requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_safe) before making Get Request.

Check out your endpoint with curl, postman or other api development tools.
If your backend responds with 200, then try adding `HEAD` to `@api_view` decorator.

```py
@api_view(['HEAD', 'GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def fetch_model(request):
    # rest of your code
```